# Fetch the latest version of a Maven artifact using search.maven

Tags: maven

I need to fetch with an HTTP GET the latest version of the following Maven artifact as a JSON document:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-core

I'm trying with search.maven.org:

https://search.maven.org/?g=org.keycloak&a=keycloak-core&sort=latest&core=gav&rows=1

However I'm not getting anything as response
Previously I have been using "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/" but recently I see this is going in timeout quite often

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not astonished because you are using the front end and not the backend API...https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/

Comment: Seems you haven't read the part where I said "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch" (backend REST API) is going in timeout quite often

Comment: I have read that but the question is in which situations etc. The written parts in your post do not use the REST API ... and will never work...